# Map video texture to a half sphere in Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, 3d-meshes, virtual-reality, 360-video

I'm new to unity3D. and am trying to play a 360-degree video. But instead of mapping the whole 360-degree (equirectangular) video to the whole sphere, I need to map the half-video to a half-sphere object. How can I do that? So basically we'll have two half-sphere, tied together, each playing the half of 360-degree video, as if a single video is mapped to a whole sphere. An example or tutorial for a beginner would be great.

e.g. So the top half of this 360 video should be textured on such mesh

**UPDATE:** No worries...we not cropping the video on the go! It is already cropped as two separate videos)

[image]  [image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to which stage you're having difficulty with. Is it the unwrapping itself, or implementation within the engine? Also, why are you splitting the sphere in two instead of just using a whole sphere? This is important as using a whole sphere would be easier to implement.